# how to cross direct user with google analytics

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

After a user fills in my "new" user form on "example-one.com", the "create" controller creates the record in the db. Then it does a redirect_to to an external site "payment-checkout.com". I have setup the Google Analytics code on both sites.

Google provides two functions _link and _linkByPost for use to use in any links or forms that go to your external domains. The problem is the user is being redirected by the controller action outside of the view and I cant use those two javascript functions to pass on the relevent G.A. info - what do i do?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way `_link` works is by passing the Google Analytics cookies from your first domain via a query string to your second domain. The second domain, if configured correctly, will accept those URL parameters and apply them as cookie values for the purposes of tracking.

So, it shouldn't be difficult for you to apply your own version of the `_link` function.

Specifically, the `_link` function passes the following cookies:

`__utma`, `__utmb`, `__utmc`, `__utmx`, `__utmz`, `__utmv` and `__utmk`

Into a query string as such: `?__utma=87278922.614105561.1288923931.1294376393.1298325957.6&__utmb=87278922.1.10.1298325957&__utmc=87278922&__utmx=-&__utmz=87278922.1288923931.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)&__utmv=-&__utmk=72493274`

So, all you need to do to replicate the `_link` function is, before you apply the server side redirect, grab the cookie values, and apply them as a query string on the URL you're redirecting to.

Now, that's not the only thing you'll need to do to get this working. The Google Analytics configuration on the payment site will need to be configured with `_setAllowLinker` set to true, as well as potentially disabling the domain hash and setting a particular domain name for the tracking cookies; it depends on your configuration. You can find out more about that in [Google Analytics Cross Domain Tracking Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html).

Comment: thanks for you help. this answer helped me tremendously so marking as best answer.

Answer (score 2):

@yc's approach looks like the best bet but if that doesn't work, I would suggest having your controller redirect the user to a "temp" page on your site itself and show some text like "Checking out....Please wait..." and using Javascript trigger the call to the "_link" function to redirect the user to the "payment-checkout.com" (again using Javascript).

Comment: nice idea, one i contemplated but it adds an extra step before getting the customers money. If this wasnt an issue i would have gone with this. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're also tracking the page the user returns to and want to measure how many users you lose in the process in between?

My knowledge of the Google Analytics API is fairly limited, so maybe there's a better solution, but you could consider rendering a page containing the GA code and triggering the _link() function from there?

It might also be possible to perform an AJAX call on submitting the form (maybe using remote_form_for) and handling the GA redirect in an RJS-response:

```
page << "_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://example.com/test.html']);"
```

However, I'm not sure how well that would fit into your application.